# How to position a group of elements at the bottom of mobile device's screen without using margin-top?

Tags: css

I would like to achieve this kind of look on my game settings:

[image]

The menu buttons are perfectly positioned at the bottom. But, I've achieved this using this stupid hack code of mine:

```
.settings-btns {
  margin-top: 10.7rem;
}
```

The problem is when I comment this line of code out, I get this:

[image]

It's the same device width and height. The buttons go up because there's no margin-top applied (of course). If I'm going to calculate the `margin-top` of these buttons on **every device**, man! that'll be a lot of work and it would not be very practical, I guess.

I suppose there is a better solution for this but I really don't know what it is. Has it got to do something with the background?

```
.background {
  background: url(../img/background.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Or has it something to do with the container? (the container that covers the whole screen of the mobile device. I had this because I am using this container on the **desktop** media query.)

```
.container {
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

I really don't know so please kindly help me.

Comment: Can you also post your HTML or a reproducible example. So that we can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **container can be adaptive to the device height using percentage or [view port units](https://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)**:

```
.container {
  border: 2px solid white;
  border-top: 0;
  border-bottom: 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* using viewport */
  height: 100vh;
 }
```

You could also add the background image to the container itself but if you do it on another division just **adapt the height to the container parent**:

```
.background {
  background: url('https://www.gstatic.com/chat/hangouts/bg/bbafcf27dfe823a255e7fa549b5b6ba5-Matiash-01.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
}
```

And finally, for the settings buttons, I would use **position fixed** and the bottom property to decide how far from the end of the page they should be displayed:

```
.settings-btns {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 30px;
}
```

I'm attaching a [small example snippet](https://codepen.io/DavidBendahan/pen/GRovaQo):

```css
.container {
  /* using viewport */
  height: 100vh;
}

.background {
  background: url('https://www.gstatic.com/chat/hangouts/bg/bbafcf27dfe823a255e7fa549b5b6ba5-Matiash-01.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
}

.settings-btns {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 30px;
}

.settings-btns button {
  padding: 10px 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="background">
    <div class="settings-btns">
      <button>button 1</button>
      <button>button 2</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope it helped!

Comment: Oh hey @DavidBenDahan, I think this usage of viewport height cuts the background image whenever I scroll down on my document. I had to remove the `overflow: hidden` from the `container` because there are other sections on my project that needs some scrolling because its content's long. Is there a solution for this?

Comment: Glad to hear it helped @Zedd! You can change the background image display using  `background-size: contain;` to make sure that the image will be fully displayed :)  Let me know if it helped! best of luck!!

Comment: I tried doing this but it didn't solve the problem. But I was able to figure it out. I added `overflow: auto` on my `.container` and my background image wasn't cut by the viewport!

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you have not tried yet, did you try giving the container height: 100% and position: relative, then align the buttons to the bottom by using css properties position: absolute and bottom: 0px ?